# Which service applications are automatically started when we install Sharepoint 2013 and why

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

In Sharepoint 2013 we have few service applications, but some of them are started by default when we install Sharepoint. Which are these service application and why are they automatically started when Sharepoint is installed.

Answer (score 0):

there is difference between the Service Application and Services running.

When you configured the farm then "Application Discovery and Load Balance Service Application" service application is configured by default. reset you have to configure manually i.e UPA, search, State etc